# Impact of indexes in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-indexes

I added some indexes in one PostgreSQL table, I actually add them to all the columns which are foreign key to another table.

Now, SELECT statements which are using those columns are 5-10 times faster than before,

```
SELECT * FROM table where indexed_column_fk=5000
```

but ordinary SELECT statement

```
SELECT * from table
```

is much slower (almost 2x slower).

How this is possible?

Also when I use EXPLAIN ANALYZE I am getting that Total cost raised with indexes?

UPDATE: SELECT * from table
with indexes

```
Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..26440.40 rows=343040 width=86) (actual time=0.292..756.614 rows=343040 loops=1)
Planning Time: 72.249 ms
Execution Time: 766.601 ms
```

without indexes  (when I drop them)

```
Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..26440.40 rows=343040 width=86) (actual time=0.022..194.712 rows=343040 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.095 ms
Execution Time: 204.613 ms
```

I run this on my local PC using pgAdmin 4

Update 2

Results after cache warm-up

[image: select * from table]

Update 3 - for ilustration purposes: when I scan table using index

[image]

Comment: I cannot believe that. Does it get faster again after dropping the indexes? If not, something else is the cause.

Comment: Could you please share the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output so we can take a look?

Comment: Hi, I updated question with EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Comment: Cache warm-up. Hint: perform the first query **twice**, then drop the index and perform the scond query. (and don't use pgadminX for performance measurements)

Comment: Based on your `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, even though you had an index, the query planner never thought it would be advantageous to use it. You would’ve seen `Index Scan` instead of `Seq Scan`, but in both cases the `Seq Scan` appears. Try adding more rows and you may see the query planner choose `Index Scan`

Comment: @wildplasser I tried what you suggest. I got similar results for both cases, which should be expected as "SELECT * FROM table" don't use any indexes and therefore shouldn't be any faster. However this time it isn't either slower. Picture above #update2